# Switch dropbox account on one computer

Tags: dropbox

I am not sure how this happened, but I apparently have two dropbox accounts, with my office computer (the dropbox app, not the web app) linking to one account and my home computer linking to the other.

I've tried to change the account it logs into but can't seem to find out how to change it. Any suggestions? I can change the account on dropbox.com, but not on my dropbox folder on my computer.

Answer (score 2):

Right click on dropbox icon in notification area.

Go to settings icon.

Click on preferences > Advanced.
Move dropbox folder to another location to save current dropbox account data.

Then, go to 
Account > Unlink this computer. It will give you option to link with another account.

Add new account, select 'continue with full setup' and select 'advanced'. Select appropriate different location to save new dropbox separately. Make sure that it should not conflict with old dropbox folder location.